# Cant save BIML file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, biml

I have just started trying to use BIML to generate my SSIS packages. Im currently using VIsual studio 2015 to do everything.

When I add a new BIML file to the project it appears in the Solution explore and I can open the file and edit it. But when I save and close and reopen none of the changes where saved. Is there a setting that i need to change in Visual Studio? Currently I have to edit this file through the use of Notepad++ or something similar.

[Visual Studio ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDZwJ.png)

Comment: Windows 7 by the way?

Comment: It's windows 10

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I have seen the same issue in VS2017 for any BIML file not in the Miscellaneous folder. Yours is in that folder though...

Comment: @Dan and Kas, Varigence is aware of the issue and the beta build I just tested appears to address the issue. You might ping support@varigence.com to see if you can get access, otherwise, I'd assume the release is going live soon-ish

Comment: Thanks billinkc for the information

Answer (score 2):

As a work around to this issue, you could right click on the file you wish to edit and choose `XML (Text) Editor`.

Sadly you'll loose intellisence for the C# code

If you open a file twice, once in the BIML editor and once in the XML editor then you can view side by side making your changes in XML but viewing nice formatting in BIML...